# IBM WebSphere Message Broker SOAP request timeout

Tags: wcf, soap, timeout, websphere, messagebroker

Created .NET WCF service, tested it - works. 
Generated schemas from Data and service contracts, put messages to Message Broker generated Message Flow from it, tested it using simple mapping (requestMessage=responceMessage) - works. Also I can reach MB from another application and send/recieve SOAP messages.
But when I try to create request to my WCF web service using defined schema and real service address (insted of mapping) my request dies after timeout.
What config issues or another settings could cause this issue?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I understand the tests you've done:

You want

```
 WMB  --SOAP-->  WCF Service
```

You have done

```
 TestClient --SOAP--> WCF Service
```

and (this where I'm not clear, you say "Also I can reach MB from another application and send/recieve SOAP messages"

```
 WMB  --SOAP-->  Another Service
```

(If you haven't done this then this is what I'd try).

Next, can you run your TestClient on the WMB machine? My guess is that you are somehow not reaching the WCF machine. Do you specify hostname, fully qualified host name or ipaddress of the WCF service machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you problem is that the request is taking too long and therefore timing out, have a look at Harry's answer to the following question:

[Time out issue in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341114/time-out-issue-in-wcf)